# How can I control which row is left by a GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

## tv_shows

```
id    |    title
-------------------------
1        The X-Files
2        Mr. Robot
```

## episodes

```
tv_show_id    |    title        |    epoch_airtime
----------------------------------------------------
1                My Struggle        15249204282
1                Via Negativa       11023920382
1                Requiem            10292092022
2                Finale             15020392031
```

## expected output

```
tv_shows.title    |    episodes.title    |    episodes.epoch_airtime
---------------------------------------------------------------------
The X-Files            My Struggle            15249204282
Mr. Robot              Finale                 15020392031
```

I want my query to return the next unaired episode of each show, along with its airtime and the show's title. So only one X-Files episode should be in the result set, and it should be whichever is airing next.

My query right now is:

```
SELECT episodes.title, episodes.airtime, tv_shows.title
FROM episodes 
JOIN tv_shows on episodes.tv_show_id = tv_shows.id
WHERE episodes.airtime > <CURRENT_EPOCH_TIME>
GROUP BY tv_shows.title;
```

The `<CURRENT_EPOCH_TIME>` bit is just a placeholder for this post, I'm going to use a parameterised query and the current epoch time in my program, ignore that.

This returns one episode of each show, but it's the episode *furthest in the future* -- or the last one in the database -- when I want the opposite. `ORDER BY` statements seem to juggle the order of the resultset, but not which results are picked up. This one's stumping me a little, and Google and the reference book I have on my desk aren't helping. I'd love it if someone could explain what the solution to this kind of problem is.

Comment: @jWeaver I've updated the post with expected output.

Comment: which RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server) ?

Comment: @jWeaver I was hoping the answer could be cross-platform. I'm using SQLite in development and MySQL in production.

Comment: It is not always possible to write cross-platform. Since, some RDBMS has some inbuilt features/function some doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle/SQL Server, Not sure about SQLite

```
    SELECT SHOWTITLE ,EPSTITLE ,AIRTIME FROM 
(select tv_shows.title ShowTitle
        ,episodes.title EpsTitle
        ,episodes.epoch_airtime AirTime
        , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY episodes.tv_shows_id order by episodes.epoch_airtime DESC) RNK
    from tv_shows inner join 
        episodes on episodes.tv_shows_id=tv_shows.id) T
WHERE RNK=1;
```